# Google Authentication Api key not found

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth

My website is based on PHP (Wordpress) and has been working perfectly fine until (29 September 2018) when it started to throw an error.

**API Key not found. Please pass a valid API key**

Here is the full stacktrace

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google_ServiceException: 
Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2v2userinfo?key=DummyKeyForStackOverflow: (400)
API Key not found. Please pass a valid API key. in /home2/domainName/***/src/io/Google_REST.php:66

Stack trace:
#0 /home2/domainName/***/src/io/Google_REST.php(36): Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#1 /home2/domainName/***/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(177):Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) 
#2 /home2/domainName/***/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php(37):Google_ServiceResource->__call('get', Array)
#3 /home2/domainName/***/3rdparty.php(176):Google_UserinfoServiceResource->get()
#4 /home2/domainName/***/user_dashboard_profile.php(110): mymethod_goo in /home2/domainName/***/src/io/Google_REST.php on line 66
```

I thought probably the Api key is expired and regenerated and used it but the error is not fixed.

I didn't make any change to my website for last few months, so there are no chances of breaking a working code. Is there any recent update to Google API which I need to incorporate in my code.

Comment: Pls add some description and code of what api you are calling - e.g. are you allowing login with google or allowing some app to access data from your website?

Comment: Check your google API console for error code/information.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using WP Estate Theme in your WordPress. This theme is using Google API developer Key for accessing Google Maps API and the key probably expired.

Here you can find very detail step by step guide how to obtain new API Key from Google and how to enter it into WP Estate Theme:
https://helpv4.wpestatetheme.org/article/google-api-key/

That API KEY is stored in the `wp_estate_google_api_key` WordPress option.